# Can Pause frames be transmitted from one interface to another on a single host? (flow control)

Tags: linux, ethernet

If I have a 1G egress NIC and 10G ingress NIC on a single Linux host (ixgbe NIC driver), is it possible that one NIC would throttle the other with flow control / pause frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes.

In practice however, pause frames are the result of a flow exceeding a hosts ingress capacity. This implies that there's a flow from one host NIC to the other - which is unlikely.

Usually, a network layer (L3) protocol is used, most likely IP. The host's IP stack *routes* each packet, so packets from one NIC's IP address to the other NIC's IP address are short-circuited through the stack - they're not sent over the wire. That eliminates a flow across both NICs unless you're using a protocol directly on top of the data link layer (L2) which doesn't route (or you have another scenario which precludes internal routing - in a virtualization scenario for instance).